# Regex expression of first 3characters should be like SRU

Tags: regex

Can any one help me for implementing the regex expression for implementing the below conditions:

1. First characters should be REF
2. Next character should be hypen
3. Next 4 characters should be digits/alphabets
4. Next character should be hypen
5. Next 4 characters should be digits/alphabets

Eg: REF-12AB-1A3B

I am trying like this.

```
^(UAD){3}[*0-9a-zA-Z]{4}[*0-9a-zA-Z]{4}$
```

But i am not able to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want something like this:

```
^REF-[0-9a-zA-Z]{4}-[0-9a-zA-Z]{4}$
```

you were missing the hyphen and there is no need for the "*" inside the list

Answer (score 1):

```
^REF-\w{4}-\w{4}$
```

`^REF` matches the characters REF- literally at start (case sensitive)

`\w{4}` matches any word character exactly 4 times

`\w` equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, if you don't need to include `_` you can replace it with `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

```
^(REF)-([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})-([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?
`REF-([0-9a-zA-Z]{4})-\1`

Comment: please give us a sample input or refine your requirements